# How to draw an arc segment from same start point till some certain degree?

Tags: wpf

I want to use an arc segment in WPF to draw an arc from 0 to 180 degrees with the same start point and different end point (depending on user angle input).
Can you kindly guide on how I can calculate the End Point depending on user input?

[image: 60 degrees arc]

[image: 180 degrees arc]

I have tried following methods but with no success.

```
<Path Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="10">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="50,10">
                <ArcSegment
                    x:Name="arcSegment"
                    Size="40,40"
                    SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                    IsLargeArc="True"
                    Point="50,10" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

```
double degrees = 60;
            if (degrees < 0)
                arcSegment.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
            else
                arcSegment.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
            double radius = 40;
            double centerX = 50;
            double centerY = 50;
            double angleInRadians = (degrees - 90) * (Math.PI / 180);

            double x = centerX + radius * Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
            double y = centerY + radius * Math.Sin(angleInRadians);

            // Set the endpoint of the ArcSegment
            arcSegment.Point = new Point(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circular arc with radius 40 and a center point at 50,50 that sweeps from left to right has a start point at 10,50 (not 50,10).

A 180 degree arc for example would de defined like this:

```
<PathFigure StartPoint="10,50">
    <ArcSegment
        x:Name="arcSegment"
        Size="40,40"
        SweepDirection="Clockwise"
        Point="90,50" />
</PathFigure>
```

The end point of the arc as a function of the sweep angle would be calculated like this:

```
private void SetArcEndPoint(double angle)
{
    double radius = 40;
    double centerX = 50;
    double centerY = 50;
    double angleInRadians = angle * Math.PI / 180;

    double x = centerX - radius * Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
    double y = centerY - radius * Math.Sin(angleInRadians);

    arcSegment.Point = new Point(x, y);

    arcSegment.SweepDirection = angle < 0
        ? SweepDirection.Counterclockwise
        : SweepDirection.Clockwise;

    arcSegment.IsLargeArc = Math.Abs(angle % 360) > 180;
}
```